# how to encode my data for it to fit a random forrest regressor?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, data-science

I have a dataset in which out of 3600 data lines, one feature "Test_8" is missing in 1000 of these. The values currently in my dataset are 2018.0 (2329 times) and 2019.0 (242 times), possibly indicating a year (though the type is a bit weird). I wanted to create a predictor to get its prediction for the 1000 missing values, but I have 2 problems:

1. I have a few tens of places where there are other missing values (only 2 other features has missing lines - test_1 and test_8).
2. I didn't manage to encode this kind of data so that the random forrest classifier will be able to work with it.

Here is the head of my data:

```
Test_0  Test_1  Test_2  Test_3  Test_4  Test_5  Test_6  Test_7  Test_8  Test_9  Test_10 Test_11 Test_12 Test_13 Test_14 Test_15 RMA
0   261.36  E   Low OP-1    True    102.14  False   True    2018.0  58.9    nov 136 1   120 1   TP-1549 False
1   268.62  H   Mid OP-17   True    655.42  False   True    2018.0  62.0    apr 114 1   152 2   TP-1549 False
2   297.66  F   Low OP-1    True    605.50  False   False   2018.0  65.1    nov 285 3   116 4   TP-1549 False
3   515.46  NaN Low OP-17   True    144.78  True    True    2018.0  83.7    jan 208 1   93  2   TP-1549 False
4   290.40  D   Low OP-4    True    416.22  False   True    2019.0  37.2    may 58  2   334 1   TP-1549 False
```

Here is my code:

```
df_with_Test_8_encoded = pd.factorize(df_with_Test_8)
df_with_Test_8_encoded.head()
```

The error I get:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2571,17) into shape (2571,)
```

Comment: I'd consider how to fill your NaN's since the algo won't work properly with NaNs or Infs. Also, I asked a similar question which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72046819/labelencoder-and-onehotencoder-within-the-same-for-loop)

Comment: You are trying to `factorize` the entire dataframe while you should be trying to encode only one column and this is causing the ValueError. You still likely won't be able to make it work since there are missing values. You need to either get rid of them or figure out a way of imputation